# Jfoenix Elements is not working on my Javafx project

Tags: java, jfoenix

Made a project with Maven with Javafx 17.0.1. I have tried adding the Jfoenix Dependencies to my `pom.xml` download the sources and refresh the project but when adding

OpenJDK 17.0.1

```
@FXML
    private JFXButton JFoenixbtn;
```

it don't know the right term to say but when there's a red line there's a problem

i added this to my `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

[Here is the Red line i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUDRG.png)